# Can I use Google Drive with two accounts?

Tags: windows-7, google-drive

I know I can switch between two different accounts with Google Drive on the web, but,
can I use two Google Drive accounts at the same time in Windows 7?

Comment: https://www.odrive.com seems to do the work (no, I don't work there/ know them)

Comment: Just tried odrive and it seems to do the trick.  As a bonus, I save a lot of system memory by not having to run different cloud providers' software as separate applications.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have two Google Drive accounts running simultaneously on PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/1035053/is-it-possible-to-have-two-google-drive-accounts-running-simultaneously-on-pc). I am flagging this question as a duplicate due to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/449254/can-i-use-google-drive-with-two-accounts/1397172#1397172) answer being submitted

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to Google's official page It's not possible to use Google Drive for your Mac/PC with more than one account at the same time: [Switch between multiple Google Drive accounts - Google Drive Help](https://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2375023)

> It's not possible to use Google Drive for your Mac/PC with more than one account at the same time.
>
> If you want to use Google Drive for your Mac/PC with a different account, disconnect the account you're signed into and sign into another account. We don't recommend doing this frequently, as you'll need to create a new Google Drive folder every time you switch accounts.

Another user posted [a poor solution](https://plus.google.com/114892703028341590446/posts/1mYzdE5KKgv) (in my opinion):

> Setup multiple user-accounts on your computer, setup Google Drive client software under each user-account, syncing with a different Google account from each one. Share the folders with your main account. As long as you keep the other user-accounts logged in, Google Drive will keep syncing for all the accounts you've set up.

Answer (score 4):

Try [Insync](https://www.insynchq.com) which is a dropbox-like service for Google users that support multiple Google Drive accounts. I think this one will solve your problem. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

My answer from this question: [Is it possible to have two Google Drive accounts running simultaneously on PC?](https://superuser.com/q/1035053/495155)

Yes. Recently Google added the feature "add account" to the Google Drive desktop application "Backup and Sync by Google", which makes it very easy to do.

1. Right-click the "Backup and Sync by Google" icon in "hidden icons" section of the taskbar. It doesn't matter which one you pick if there's more than one icon. [image: image1]
2. Click the 3 dots, and then click "Add New Account". [image: image2]
3. Follow the instructions to log in and sync whatever folders you want.
4. They should stay synced/mirrored. I'm not sure if you restart the computer, you'll have to do this process again -- I haven't tested. There doesn't seem to be an option to see a list of your accounts currently added.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem, not only on my Mac but I also wanted to access all three of my Drives from my iPad and iPhone as well. I've found a small and simple workaround to simply combine your drives.

> 1. Make a folder in your main drive called ‘My other Google Drive’ (or whatever you’d like to call it)
> 2. On your other Google Drive, share your folder(s) with yourself (your main account) and adjust it so you ‘Can edit’
> 3. On your main account, go to ‘Shared with me’ and drag this folder (or these folders) to the folder you just made (‘My other Google Drive’)

[Source](http://www.terinova.net/access-multiple-google-drives-from-one-account/)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. I have done it for you this time

Answer (score 0):

CloudFuze.com offers management across multiple accounts .

Download Free : www.cloudfuze.com/access-google-drive-multiple-accounts/

Comment: Welcome to Super User! We generally frown upon excessive self-promotion. Please try to keep your answers relevant and make sure your answers aren't all about your product.

Comment: Be sure that answers actually answer the question, if you have a comment that is not an answer it is best to leave it as a comment.

Comment: @zeel It seems that this tool does exactly what the OP wants, namely using two Drive accounts at the same time. Also, users with less than 50 reputation cannot leave comments

Comment: The question asked if you can use two accounts at once, not if there was an application to get around the fact that you can not.

Comment: @zeel Exactly: The question asked if you can use two accounts at once, and if there happens to be an application that allows you to do so, that's a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

All options suggested here up until now are either hacks or cost money.

It seems that there is a new service in town, [odrive](http://odrive.com), allows multiple accounts from multiple could services to be synced for free.

Hope they will stay free.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Backup and Sync for my personal account and Drive for Desktop for my work account. They are technically two different software, which default to two different local storage locations. You can download them both here.

https://www.google.com/drive/download/

Answer (score -1):

You can try [Otixo](http://otixo.com/). It is web app that allows managing multiple cloud accounts online (e.g. copying files between accounts) and also allows access to Otixo in Windows by [WebDav](http://otixo.desk.com/customer/portal/articles/676081-otixo-via-webdav).

EDIT: From now Otixo is no longer free...