# Is it possible to have two Google Drive accounts running simultaneously on PC?

Tags: file-transfer, google-drive

I need to transfer files between two Google Drive accounts frequently. It is preferable to have two Google Drive accounts running simultaneously.

Is it possible to have two Google Drive accounts running simultaneously on PC?

Other alternatives are also welcome.

Comment: Why not simply "Share" your Gdrive folder from 1 acc (Acc A) to the other one (Acc B)? Then you'll have full access (assuming that is the shared condition) to the other drive folder. And also stuff "shared with me" you can have your own copy by choosing "Add to my drive". If you need the reverse to happen, simply do the same, share folder from Acc A into Acc B.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Recently Google added the feature "add account" to the Google Drive desktop application "Backup and Sync by Google", which makes it very easy to do.

1. Right-click the "Backup and Sync by Google" icon in "hidden icons" section of the taskbar. It doesn't matter which one you pick if there's more than one icon. [image: image1]
2. Click the 3 dots, and then click "Add New Account". [image: image2]
3. Follow the instructions to log in and sync whatever folders you want.
4. They should stay synced/mirrored. I'm not sure if you restart the computer, you'll have to do this process again -- I haven't tested. There doesn't seem to be an option to see a list of your accounts currently added.

Comment: I don't know. Perhaps try using Torch Browser or other Chrome based browser, so that you can log in twice?

Comment: @Mawg Sorry I don't understand what part you're talking about. What issue are you referring to?

Comment: Well, I don't use Google Drive, but I doubt that you can use it twice on one copy of Chrome, or you likely wouldn't be asking.  So, what about two copies of Chrome? Nope. So, what about Chrome and another browser ? If it neds to be based on Chrome for some reason, use something like Torch Browser, which is base don Chrome. Else just use Chrome & FireFox. Sorry, i was just thinking aloud - about something that I don't really know much about :-/

Comment: @mawg This is talking about Google Drive as a desktop app. No need for browsers. But I see, no problem!

Comment: D'oh! Silly me. I wasn't aware that it was a desktop app (+1). Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Pulled from this [Article](http://www.guidingtech.com/17243/run-multiple-google-drive-instances-windows-sync-accounts/)

**Step 1**: Close all instances of Google Drive running on your computer and then download and install this [application](http://www.guidingtech.com/16728/what-is-environment-system-variable-edit-windows/). After the application is installed, add C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Drive to your Windows Environment Variable.

You can refer to this [article](http://v2.nonxt6.c.pack.google.com/edgedl/drive/1.0.2891.6813/gsync.msi) to see how it’s done.

**Step 2**: Having done that, open Notepad and copy paste the following line. Don’t forget to replace username@ domain.com with your Google username.

```
  @ECHO OFF
SET USERNAME=username@ domain.com
SET USERPROFILE=%~dp0%USERNAME%
SET USERPROFILE=%~dp0%USERNAME%
MD “%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming”>nul
MD “%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Application Data”>nul
MD “%USERPROFILE%\Application Data”>nul
MD “%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data”>nul
MD “%USERPROFILE%\My Documents”>nul
MD “%USERPROFILE%\Documents”>nul
START googledrivesync
```

Save the file as **Account 1.bat** to your desktop or another folder where you would like to sync the files. Don’t forget to select All Files as type in Notepad while saving the batch file.

**Step 3**: Now run the batch file and wait for another instance of Google Drive to Start. The second instance of the application will ask you to sign in to a new account. Proceed normally, just remember to change the sync folder to the new folder that’s created using the batch files in the advanced option.

**Note**: Sometimes you might encounter some difficulty while changing the folder. In such a case, copy the exact path of the folder to select the directory.

Comment: Fix the quotes please, they must be like this `"`

Comment: @colthreepv do you mean a single quote `'` instead of double quotes `"` ?

Comment: @Vylix no, the user @NetworkKingPin used `“` instead of `"`. Slighty different for humans, very different for machines

Comment: Microsoft word has and habit of using so-called `smart quotes`. You can turn this off in auto-correct options