# Is it possible to transfer a folder from one Google Drive account to another?

Tags: google-drive

Not the entire account, just a folder, including all files and sub-folders and their files (recursively).

And not transferring a folder from one folder from another, transfer the folder from one account (user) to an entirely different account (user).

And not by downloading or sync'ing it to a local machine, can't do that.

I don't just want to share it. I want to move it to the new user's account so that it can be deleted from the old user's account.

Context: Too much data in a large complex hierarchy of folders clogging up gdrive (terrabytes).  Need to move it off to a different account so that the starting account has less storage and can be sync'd and come within Googles storage limits.  Don't want to just remove it.

Bottom line: Need to copy the hierarchical folder structure to a different user account, then removing it from the starting one.

Comment: What you want is not possible without either downloading the contents and uploading to the other account or sharing the account and downloading and uploading the contents

Comment: unless the software you are using has specifically provided a feature for copying from one account to another, anything you do will involve downloading the data to your system and uploading it to the new target. server2server stuff cannot be accomplished in a client browser, unless the web application has been specifically designed to do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to have two Google Drive accounts running simultaneously on PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/1035053/is-it-possible-to-have-two-google-drive-accounts-running-simultaneously-on-pc)